# Change order of Author / Title /Date in a book

Tags: formatting, titles, author, front-matter, date

This is probably very basic question. I need to create a book with FrontPage: Author/Title/Publisher-Date.Like this:

[image: Front Page + Text page]

All is centered in title page, and in text page Title is left and text is justified.

Any help, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. What document class are you using? It might make the most sense to use a class like `memoir` which has extensive facilities built in for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best if you just lay out the title page as you want it. For example:

```
% titlepageprob.tex  SE 563559

\documentclass{memoir} % or book
%\documentclass{book} % or memoir
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % no page number
\begin{center}
\sffamily % sansserif fonts
\bfseries % bold fonts

\vspace{2cm}
\Large John A. Smith

\vspace{4cm}
\LARGE TITLE OF HIS BOOK

\vspace{8cm}
\large Publisher Inc., \\
New York, 2020

\end{center}

\chapter*{Unnumbered chapter}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Set the `\vspace` lengths to suit your design. If you use the `memoir` class you can have some larger font sizes if needed.

Comment: Thank you. This work. :-)